# Inconsistency between immediate window output vs runtime output

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was debugging some code with immediate window and the output is always consistent with my expected output.

But in fact I was wrong and the immediate window's output is wrong too!

[image]

The run time output is `false` while the immediate window says `true`

OK now that I know what I was trying to do was wrong, what i do not know is why the Immediate Window behaves like this? Is there anything I need to watch out for in the future when using it?

Comment: This is standard lossage in the new managed debugging engine, it is very buggy.  Two workarounds, use Tools > Options > Debugging > General.  Tick the "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators".  And the more powerful one, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  Which enables the good debugging engine that the previous team created.  The only reason these options exist is because they are well-aware that the new stuff has a lot of problems.  Solves your problem, but do consider to just focus on your bugs instead of the debugger team's bugs :)  I know.

Comment: It has been reported ~6 months ago: [Immediate window returning wrong results](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159250/immediate-window-returning-wrong-results.html) (Under Investigation)

Comment: @HansPassant interesting to know! thanks for the workaround